# memory leak when using NSURLConnection instance

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

I have an ImageDownloader class with NSURLConnection* connection as an ivar which initializes it setting its delegate as self.
Now the doubt is when I init an ImageDownloader instance in my AsyncImageView so that my image downloading is started it has a retain count =2 {1 with image downloader init and 2 with nsurl init setting delegate as self}. So when i release image downloader from my asyncImageView it still has a retain count =1.

How do I release the imageDownloader instance because there is probably a leak?
If I release connection ivar in imageDownloader the retain count should be 0 but then the app crashes(for obv. reasons).

Comment: post the debugger crash function call trace and your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, NSURLConnection instance retains its delegate. So you should call [connection cancel] to release it before releasing ImageDownloader instance.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, i guess the connection releases the delegate once it has loaded the data(i.e called the required delegate methods). Do we explicitly need to cancel the connection?

Comment: Yes you're right, you should cancel connection only if it is not finished yet. It is described in NSURLConnection class reference: "The connection retains delegate. It releases delegate when the connection finishes loading, fails, or is canceled."